# BeautifulSoup not deterministic?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

When I run this code, the attributes come out in a different order each time. Does anyone know why?

I've tried searching BeautifulSoup random/non-deterministic but couldn't find anything.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<span class="pb-byline" itemprop="author" itemscope="" 
itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">By 
<a href="https://www.washingtonpost.com/people/joe-bloggs/">
<span itemprop="name">Joe Bloggs</span></a></span>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
find_span = soup.find('span')
print(find_span.attrs)
```

Now that I know, I can sort them but I'm very curious to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access `find_span.attrs`, you are accessing a `dictionary`. These have **no** order, so to talk about the order in which it `prints` is not logical.

A `dictionary` is just a set of `key : value` pairs. It has no implicit order, just that each `key` will always give its corresponding `value`. Hence, `printing` it means that these `pairs` may come in any order.

Comment: I guess - still seems odd that it wouldn't be deterministic.

Comment: @TroyWray Well when I try your code multiple times, it *does* give the same output so maybe it's that you are using slightly different data each time...

Comment: I'm running the exact same code in PyCharm (set as 3.5.1) multiple times and getting different order. Obviously not every time but it readily gives different order.

Comment: @TroyWray Well then I guess it must be down to how `PyCharm` handles it... sorry, it's not going to impact anything anyway though if you right the rest of your `code` right